# Updating linear regression with many features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, dask, gradient-descent

The problem I have is the following:

I have a csv file with roughly 10 million rows. With that, I want to to run a linear regression with many interaction terms. In the end I will have 3000 such interactions. So creating them by hand would give a dataset of shape (10mio, 3000) which won't fit into memory anymore. Furthermore, I need to center these interactions terms prior to fitting.

Fixed effects are not possible as the interactions contain continouus variables and not true dummies (they will have mostly 0, some 1, and few 0.5).

The plan I have for now is the following:

1. Use dask (http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) to read in the csv file. Then create the interactions and save them out of core so that I don't have memory problems, here pandas would fail. How can I create the interactions with dask efficiently?
2. Center the created interaction terms with sklearn's StandardScaler (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler). Should I just loop over a reasonable amount of columns (say, 100), center these 100, and store the centered variables again on disk? From the dask documentation I guess it is easily possible to combine dask with sklearn?
3. Fit the model using Stochastic Gradient Descent (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor) with the `partial_fit()` attribute to do it part by part in a loop. I am also aware of other updating ways (https://dahtah.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/rank-one-updates-for-faster-matrix-inversion/) but have not found implementations for python?
4. Predict part by part in a loop.

Do you think this is a reasonable plan?

Comment: Have you considered using Spark instead of Dask? You could load the csv into a Spark DataFrame (Similar to a Pandas DataFrame) and run the entire Pipeline in Spark just like you would run it in Sklearn.

Comment: I have also considered Spark but no experience with it. According to this comment https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/spark.html I think dask will be the better choice for my problem.